# Why doesn't this async IIFE run?

Tags: javascript

I'm being really dumb here. Why doesn't this async IIFE run?

```js
const f = () => Promise.resolve()

(async function() {  
  console.log('running async IIFE...')
  await f()
})()
```

---

Comment: lack of semicolon - that's why you should never leave them out unless you know what you're doing

Comment: AAAAAHHhhhhhhhhhggggggh

Comment: add a `console.log(f+'')` after that code to see the glory :p